# Bulk Sms Sender php

Tags: php, sql

i wanna to make a bulk sms sender service . i am Nobe in php . i am confused how to do . i have sms API and code . the given code sends too much burden on hosting  server . please guide . any better way to get rid of time out or queue system or another . how to put all numbers in database and later perform actions on them .. i wanna to 1000 sms on 1000 recipients in one click

How To Avoid timeout as the process will continues 1000 times??? may i perform same action via php header refresh post ?? if yes then how ???

```
<?php
$recepient = "923126812536,923134126153,923336088811,92.............. up to 1000 numbers";

$message = "Message for 1000 numbers"

if($submit) {

$tags = explode(',' , $recepient);
foreach ($tags as $to_x){

$url = "http://earlysms.com/free_sms_api.php?" .
         "sender="  . urlencode($sender) . "&" .
         "mobile=" . urlencode($to_x) . "&" .
         "message=" .urlencode($message);
$output = file($url);
$result = explode(":", $output[0]);    


}

?>
```

Comment: Use CURL instead of opening it as a file.

Comment: will curl execute 1000 times without timing problem ??

Comment: Might not. Consider using a cronjob to split the tasks by time.

Comment: cronjob to split the tasks by time??? how to perform???

Comment: Use Threads, or forks, or gearman, or cronjob, or PHP from client, which can all run PHP scripts without timelimit. Most HTTP have timeout 30-60 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this library

https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl

Sending SMS in parallel will improve performance

Comment: For example, you can have set max request at same time to 10, add all 1000 or more requests, then ParallelCurl will do the rest part